# Android ViewPager as an item of a GridView

Tags: android, gridview, android-viewpager, android-arrayadapter

I've seen a few questions on making a GridView span over multiple "pages" using ViewPager, but what I am trying to do is to have a ViewPager as an item within a GridView.

Here is a simple image attempting to illustrate the UI I'm after: [image desired outcome](http://i43.tinypic.com/5n2l2q.jpg)

This shows a 2 item wide grid view (expanding vertically), each item has a title and a view pager with multiple pages with the ability to "swipe" left/right to the next page in a nice animated way.

Below is the code for a very simplified version that shows the issue I am having, I've bypassed some of the normal things you would do when using ArrayAdapters:

**MainActivity.java**

```java
package com.example.viewpageringridviewtest;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "VPinGVTest";
    private ArrayList<String> mBoxes = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> mItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) mBoxes.add("Box " + i);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) mItems.add("Page " + i);
        GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
        GridAdapter adapter = new GridAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item);
        grid.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class GridAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
        public GridAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
            super(context, resource);
            mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mBoxes.size();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "GridAdapter::getView(" + position + ")");
            View v = convertView;
            Holder holder = null;
            if (v == null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Inflating R.layout.grid_item");
                v = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
                holder = new Holder(v);
                v.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Recycling view");
                holder = (Holder) v.getTag();
            }
            holder.populate(position);
            return v;
        }

        private class Holder {
            private View mRow;
            private TextView mTitle;
            private ViewPager mViewPager;
            private ItemPagerAdapter mItemPagerAdapter;
            public Holder(View v) {
                mRow = v;
                mTitle = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
                mViewPager = (ViewPager) mRow.findViewById(R.id.pager);
                mItemPagerAdapter = new ItemPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            }
            public void populate(int position) {
                mTitle.setText(mBoxes.get(position));
                mViewPager.setAdapter(mItemPagerAdapter);
            }
        }
    }

    private class ItemPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public ItemPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            Log.i(TAG, "Creating new ItemPagerAdapter");
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Creating fragment for item in position " + position);
            return new ItemFragment(mItems.get(position));

        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mItems.size();
        }
    }

    private class ItemFragment extends Fragment {
        private String mItem;

        public ItemFragment(String item) {
            mItem = item;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Inflating layout R.layout.grid_item_page");
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_page, container, false);
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_page_title)).setText(mItem);
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:columnWidth="140dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:verticalSpacing="7dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="7dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**grid_item.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FF0000">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <!-- View Pager -->
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**grid_item_page.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_page_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the image of the output [actual outcome](http://i43.tinypic.com/143dm4w.png).  As you can see the View pager is not appearing at all as though it hasn't got any content.  Using the code above, here are the log messages that I get:

```
D/VPinGVTest(2134): GridAdapter::getView(0)
D/VPinGVTest(2134): Inflating R.layout.grid_item
I/VPinGVTest(2134): Creating new ItemPagerAdapter
D/VPinGVTest(2134): GridAdapter::getView(0)
D/VPinGVTest(2134): Recycling view
D/VPinGVTest(2134): GridAdapter::getView(0)
D/VPinGVTest(2134): Recycling view
D/VPinGVTest(2134): Creating fragment for item in position 0
D/VPinGVTest(2134): Creating fragment for item in position 1
D/VPinGVTest(2134): Inflating layout R.layout.grid_item_page
D/VPinGVTest(2134): Inflating layout R.layout.grid_item_page
D/VPinGVTest(2134): GridAdapter::getView(0)
D/VPinGVTest(2134): Inflating R.layout.grid_item
I/VPinGVTest(2134): Creating new ItemPagerAdapter
D/VPinGVTest(2134): GridAdapter::getView(0)
D/VPinGVTest(2134): Recycling view
D/VPinGVTest(2134): GridAdapter::getView(0)
D/VPinGVTest(2134): Recycling view
D/VPinGVTest(2134): GridAdapter::getView(0)
D/VPinGVTest(2134): Recycling view
```

So it is calling getView(0) many times, the first time of which it creates the pager adapter and eventually create the fragments.  Further calls to getView(0) recycle the view except the 4th one which re-inflates the layout, creates the pager adapter but no fragments are created.

Appreciate if any one has any ideas of how to fix this or whether there is a better solution I can use.